# Jetty removes Content-Encoding: gzip header

Tags: gzip, jetty, content-encoding

I'm using Jetty 6.1 together with [PJL Compressing Filter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pjl-comp-filter/).

Jetty removes the following header from the response:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

This causes that most browsers cannot display the page anymore and show something like this:

```
Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED)
```

The Problem does not occur when I deploy my application on Tomcat 6.0. Also, if I disable the PJL Compressing Filter, the application works.

What can I do that Jetty leaves the header in the response?

Answer (score 0):

make it sure you're using the last available jetty version.

It does work with this configuration for me:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>mimeTypes</param-name>
      <param-value>text/html,text/plain,text/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/css,application/javascript,application/json,image/svg+xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```